# Adding .jar files to classpath

Tags: java, classpath

I am fairly new to Java and I am trying to understand how to add .jar files to my classpath.  Specifically I want to be able to import the [Stanford coreNLP Library](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp.shtml).  After downloading and unzipping coreNLP, I get 4 jar files that I need to add to my classpath which are called

```
stanford-corenlp-3.3.1.jar
stanford-corenlp-3.3.1-models.jar
xom.jar
joda-time.jar
```

[This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2396493/what-is-a-classpath-confused-and-need-a-human-touch-to-understand) shows that I can do this by writing a command that includes the location of the .jar files and the path to the package hierarchy. I obviously know the location of the .jar files but I do not know what the path to the package hierarchy should be.  I have tried

```
java -cp stanford-corenlp-3.3.1.jar;stanford-corenlp-3.3.1-models.jar;xom.jar;joda-time.jar
```

but this is clearly wrong because it only includes the .jar files.  Can someone give me some direction on how to modify the above command?  Thanks

EDIT:

The new command that I have tried is

`java -cp stanford-corenlp-3.3.1.jar;stanford-corenlp-3.3.1-models.jar;xom.jar;joda-time.jar edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP`

as per the suggestions.  However this produces the same error of

```
-bash: stanford-corenlp-3.3.1-models.jar: command not found
-bash: xom.jar: command not found
-bash: joda-time.jar: command not found
```

Just to be clear, all I want to do is be able to use

```
import edu.stanford.nlp
```

in my java file.  Also I am using a mac.

Comment: What you have is all you need (to set the classpath). But of course, you need a main class to execute.

Comment: You deal with the package hierarchies in your code, as packages.

Comment: Can you comment on the command that I provided?  It is not correct because it creates errors i.e. `file_name.jar: command not found`

Comment: You didn't provide any command containing file_name.jar. What do you want to execute, and what complete command are you using, and on which OS?

Comment: I was just using file_name.jar as a placeholder.  The actual errors were `bash: stanford-corenlp-3.3.1-models.jar: command not found
-bash: xom.jar: command not found
-bash: joda-time.jar: command not found`.

Answer (score 0):

The [website](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp.shtml) you link to gives several examples.  You need to add:

```
edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP
```

to the end of your command.  This is the `main` class and is what will be executed when you run the program.

Comment: This produces an error that I have shown in my edit.  Any idea what is going on?

Comment: @user1893354 Since you are running this in a Unix-like environment, you need to use colons, not semicolons.  Replace all the semicolons with colons.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the -cp flag as you used it but only reference the directory.

Example:

```
javac -cp ".;./classes;/path/to/jar/dir" MyProgram.java
```

Then run:

```
java -cp ".;./classes;/path/to/jar/dir" MyProgram
```

alternatively you can add the CLASSPATH as an environment variable.

In Linux/Mac you can do

`export CLASSPATH=".;./classes;/PATH/TO/JARS/"`

If you are using Windows you can follow instructions [here](https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them) to set up your environment variables.