# Creating properties file on Java classpath

Tags: java, eclipse, classpath

I want to create a properties file on my classpath then put that file in my folder, but I do not understand: what is my classpath?

I know that classpath contains jars and references to the top level folders. I also read many related threads regarding the same ([What is a classpath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2396493/what-is-a-classpath-confused-and-need-a-human-touch-to-understand)) but I want some very basic explanation for it so that I won't be confused later.

My classpath variable contains multiple values so which is the exact path and where should I create my new file?

If I try to add new file to the project and file name is "jboss-ejb-client.properties", eclipse gives an error of invalid file name???

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Anywhere in one of the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A ClassPath is a path for a specific class:
for example you have a package called `me.name.utils` and you have a a class `Bar` in it.
The classpath to it will be: `me.name.utils.Bar`

Think about folders, you have a foo.exe file on your Desktop, in this case, the package will be: `C:/Users/User/Desktop` and the class will be `foo.exe` so the "classpath" will be `C:/Users/User/Desktop/foo.exe`

Except instead of files and folders, there are packages and classes (or interfaces/anything else)