# Classpath in java and spring

Tags: java, spring, classpath

I am majorly confused about where the classpath is. I understand when we create a spring mvc, resources folder, or inside web-inf is considered classpath. And we can use "classpath:" inside xml files to declare the folder. However, where is this classpath exactly? How is it set ? I have been reading about it for a long time, i still couldnt manage to get a real clear image in my head how the classpath is initially determined etc.

For example when we create a war file, and deploy it on a tomcat server, all the resource files can still be read via given paths with "classpath:" in the xml files. How does this work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, if it's web application, the classpath begins in WEB-INF/classes.  Also, jar files in WEB-INF/lib are also on the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

The Classpath is where the JVM will look for class files and other resources. Since you are using Spring MVC, I assume you are deploying a Web application (ie WAR file). This means that the classpath is set by the container which is following the Servlet spec.

The classpath for a WAR file includes the WEB-INF/classes and WEB-INF/lib folders. The Java EE/Servlet container where the WAR file is deployed will also include other common folders in the classpath.

[Here is how Tomcat works.](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html)

You might also want to try this StackOverflow [article/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2396493/what-is-a-classpath-confused-and-need-a-human-touch-to-understand)