# Why is it that only this Java import statement for Log4j works, but not the other one?

Tags: java, import

I'm curious about how Java import works. For example, I just ran this sample log4j code, and it did not compile :

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import java.io.*;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.*;



public class log4jExample{
  /* Get actual class name to be printed on */
  static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(
                      log4jExample.class.getName());

  public static void main(String[] args)
                throws IOException,SQLException{

     log.debug("Hello this is an debug message");
     log.info("Hello this is an info message");
  }
}
```

It gives this error :

```
3 errors found:
File: C:\Users\adel\Desktop\various_topics\new_Java_Code\log4jExample.java  [line: 1]
Error: package org.apache.log4j does not exist
File: C:\Users\adel\Desktop\various_topics\new_Java_Code\log4jExample.java  [line: 13]
Error: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Logger
  location: class log4jExample
File: C:\Users\adel\Desktop\various_topics\new_Java_Code\log4jExample.java  [line: 13]
Error: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable Logger
  location: class log4jExample
```

But then I had another class, which has an import like this :

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Level;

public class HelloWorldLog4J {
```

And this one works fine. I'm just curious , where does Java actually find the those imported libraries?
thanks

Comment: What what the specific compiler error?

Comment: [What is a classpath?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2396493/what-is-a-classpath-confused-and-need-a-human-touch-to-understand) The answers mostly talk about runtime classpath, but the same thing applies to compilation time.

Comment: Imported libraries are on your classpath, and the log4j classes are in the log4j jar file.

Comment: @Rogue - added this in  . I think I'm starting to get it though, the link Sotirious gave helps

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding your question, but your import statement looks like `import org.apache.log4j.Logger;` and you say it doesn't work but `import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;` does work.  Notice that your import is missing the 'logging' portion before 'log4j'?  This is likely why yours didn't work because it wasn't complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `import` statement is a feature which allows you to use the simple names of types (and/or their members) in your source code rather than their fully qualified names. For example, the implicit

```
import java.lang.*;
```

which is added to all java compilation units (.java source files) allows you to write

```
String variable = "";
```

instead of

```
java.lang.String variable = "";
```

When you compile your source code, the compiler needs to be able to identify the types you use so that it can tell if you're using them correctly. The typical [`javac` compiler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html) has the following `-cp` option

> **`-cp path` or `-classpath path`**
>
> **Specify where to find user class files, and (optionally) annotation processors and source files.** This class path overrides the
>   user class path in the CLASSPATH environment variable. If neither
>   CLASSPATH, `-cp` nor `-classpath` is specified, the user class path
>   consists of the current directory. See Setting the Class Path for more
>   details.

This option allows you to specify the location of any compiled `.class` files (extracted or within a library archive, ex: a `.jar`).

When you compiled your code, presumably through an IDE or build tool, what actually got executed was something like

```
javac -cp "/some/folder/with/classes:log4j2.jar" com/example/log4jExample.java
```

In other words, it was referring to the log4j2 library which contains all the logging classes. You got a compilation error because your classpath did not contain a class called `org.apache.log4j.Logger` and the compiler could therefore not validate what you were trying to do. In your second attempt, the classpath  did contain a class called `org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager` (and the others).

---

`org.apache.log4j.Logger` is part of log4j 1. It not part of log4j 2.