# Is CLASSPATH variable implicit?

Tags: java, jvm, classpath

Is it mandatory to add classpath variable in commandline .
for e.g.

```
java -cp $CLASSPATH MyClass
```

I know it's mandatory if the classpath is stored in some different variable , but since CLASSPATH (the variable) is a parameter in the Java Virtual Machine, does it have to be explicity added to command line ?
I am facing a issue where if i don't add the CLASSPATH variable to command line i get NoClassDef.

Comment: Set it in the System Environment variables

Comment: You will face issue if you do not add required jars in classpath as JVM will not know where to find the class. A good explanation of classpath http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2396493/what-is-a-classpath.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `CLASSPATH` variable probably contains wildcards (*).

When you run `java -cp $CLASSPATH`, the wildcards are expanded, but not when the class path is read directly from the environment variable. Apart from this issue, `CLASSPATH` variable is automatically used by Java launcher.

Comment: Thanks . Actually I didn't export the classpath that i was creating in my shell script. Due to which CLASSPATH was not available.

Comment: Do you know if there is some special reason why the wildcard is not expanded if it is read from the environment variable?

Comment: @MarkusWeninger I mean the expansion by a shell, not by a VM. E.g. if I set `CLASSPATH=myapp*.jar` JVM won't recognize `myapp-v1.0.jar`, but if I run `java -cp $CLASSPATH`, `myapp*.jar` will be expanded to `myapp-v1.0.jar` by the shell, and this will work correctly.