# ImageView won't display the Image when it comes from project space

Tags: javafx-8

So, I am new to JavaFX and as part of a project I am attempting to use ImageView to display some images. Before adding to my actual project, I set up the following to be sure I understood how to use ImageViews.

My Controller:

```
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TestController {


    @FXML
    ImageView imageView;

    Image image;

    public void start(Stage stage){
        /*
         * THIS WORKS! 
         * 
         *  image = new   Image("file:/C://Users//Owner//Pictures//MyProjectPhotos/picture.jpg");
         */

        //BUT THIS DOESN'T :(
        image = new   Image("file:/JavaFXPractice/photos/picture.jpg");

        imageView.setImage(image);

        imageView.setOnMouseClicked(me -> System.out.println("hello"));
    }

}
```

The fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity"
 minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" 
 xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.65" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"    
 fx:controller="application.TestController">
   <children>
      <VBox layoutX="156.0" layoutY="88.0" prefHeight="272.0"    prefWidth="378.0">
         <children>
            <ImageView fx:id="imageView" fitHeight="276.0" fitWidth="378.0"   
             pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" />
          </children>
       </VBox>
    </children>
 </AnchorPane>
```

And finally this:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/view/TestPage.fxml"));
        AnchorPane root = (AnchorPane) loader.load();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.show();

        TestController control = loader.getController();
        control.start(primaryStage);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

My problem is in the TestController class. As you can see in the multi-line comment (and also the comment/line of code below it), the image displays properly when I get it from my local machine, but not when I get it from my project space. I have tried for hours now to figure this out, but every single time I try to retrieve any photo from my project space, nothing appears on the ImageView. It is not null (neither is the Image), and there are no reported errors. I have also tried searching for an answer, but no luck so far.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by "project space", perhaps you mean [classpath](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2396493/what-is-a-classpath)?  If that is the case, perhaps read the [image javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/Image.html) which explains various ways of retrieving an image.  Basically, you probably don't want to be using the `file:` protocol unless you want to get something outside your classpath.  If you continue to have issues, perhaps provide an output tree of your project target directory or `jar -tvf` output for your jar.

Answer (score 1):

You can load your images like this:

```
image = new Image(getClass().getResource("/photos/picture.jpg").toExternalForm());
```

under the assumption, that "photos" is a folder at the root of your project. This folder must be on the classpath. Depending on your IDE this can be achieved in different ways. In Eclipse this can be achieved by putting this folder into a "source folder". A typical structure is

```
project
   src
      ...
   res
      photos
         picture.jpg
```

where both "src" and "res" are source folders.