# How to include image in a self contained javafx app?

Tags: image, deployment, javafx, self-contained

recently I am dealing with including image in my JAVAFX program, I am aware of putting a URL or a an address of the directory which my image is located, but just like the way we put an icon in our program and deploy it, I want this happen to my image,because if I run the .exe file in another system that doesn't contain my image in it's local disk, it will throw a null pointer Exception and I want my image to be part of my program resource,your opinions will be a great help for me,thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of this thread
[ImageView won't display the Image when it comes from project space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36212313/imageview-wont-display-the-image-when-it-comes-from-project-space/36217114#36217114)
you will find the answer you are looking for.