# Maven - what is a resource file, classpath and bundle

Tags: java, maven

I'm new to java world and started to learn maven. I came across the following topics and it become pretty hard to find an article that explain them to unexpirienced java programmers.

[This is the tutorial I'm reading](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html#How_do_I_add_resources_to_my_JAR), please explain the following:

1. Resource files
2. Classpath (I read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2396493/what-is-a-classpath) but couldn't understand why I need to involve the OS (environment variables) which liberies I need in a specific project)
3. Bundle

Answer (score 0):

1. Resource files is any files that you want to bundle together with your java class files in the jar. These can be things like images, text files or anything else that you would like to have in the jar file in addition to your program.
2. Classpath is the set of locations that will contain Java classes or Jars that can be accessed by the classloader when your program is executed. Only classes on the classpath can be imported and used by your program.
3. With bundle I suspect you mean source bundle? This is an optional artifact that can be downloaded from maven central that contains the source code for the associated jar. The benefit of downloading the source bundle is that you can then reference the source code while developing with the jar.