# How to add dataframe src directory to java project

Tags: java

I am trying to use Dataframes in my java project. I found a library on the internet: https://github.com/cardillo/joinery. but I dont know how to add the folder to my directory and use dataframes in my project. please advise. I am new to java.

Comment: What IDE/build tools are you using? Most of time you add [tag:jar] file of your dependencies to your [build/class path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2396759/1651107)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the jar from [here](https://bintray.com/cardillo/maven/joinery/1.8) and add it to the Java project's build path.

Or if your project is `maven based Java project` then add the dependency in `pom.xml file`

```
<dependency>
<groupId>joinery</groupId>
<artifactId>joinery-dataframe</artifactId>
<version>1.8</version>
</dependency>
```

For `Gradle Based Java project` add in `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies{
compile "com.google.guava:guava:$guavaVersion"
}
```