# I can't import a package from another directory

Tags: java, import, package

I want to create two packages: the one containing problem-specific classes and methods and the one containing some typical mathematical apparatus.
I will denote them "maxim.main_package" and "maxim.algebra".
For some reason I can't import the algebra package to the main one.
Please, help.

As the algebra package does not rely on the main one, I have successfully compiled the .java file into a .class via the command line. The .java file starts with "package maxim.algebra;".
Now I want to compile the main .java file which starts with "package maxim.main;" followed by "import algebra.*;"
The paths to the .java files with are resp.:

```
1) maxim\main\main.java
2) maxim\algebra\algebra.java
I run "javac maxim\main\main.java" command from maxim directory. 
It fails saying:

    `error: cannot access Algebra
    Algebra.matrix3x3 R = Algebra.some_method(parameters)
    bad class file: .\algebra\Algebra.class
    class file contains wrong class: maxim.algebra.Algebra`
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a classpath and how do I set it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2396493/what-is-a-classpath-and-how-do-i-set-it)

Comment: A file containing the class `Algebra` **must** be named `Algebra.java`.

Comment: I believe you should also import `maxim.algebra.*`, not `algebra.*`

Comment: Lutz, the file is named Algebra.java.
Roger, no, in fact if I import maxim.algebra.*, the package and its classes are not found at all.
With import algebra.* the class is seen alright.

Comment: There's some inconsistency here. You say you run `javac maxim\main\main.java` from `maxim` directory. That shouldn't work. Did you mean `javac main\main.java` with `maxim` as current directory? If so, step up one directory, import `maxim.algebra.*` in main.java and run `javac maxim\main\main.java`.

Answer (score 0):

Package names and the directory structure needs to match. Case matters. The packages then also needs to be available on the [classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2396493/what-is-a-classpath-and-how-do-i-set-it). By default, the current directory is in the classpath. But the classpath can be changed with the environment variable `CLASSPATH`. If this variable is defined and `.` (current directory) is not in it, current directory will not be in the classpath. The classpath can also be set with the parameter  `-classpath` or `-cp` for short. See also [Setting the Class Path](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html).

Here's a short guide on how to put classes in packages and import classes from different packages:

You have two packages, `maxim.main` and `maxim.algebra`. We start off in the current directory, where we create two directories named after the package names, `maxim\main` and `maxim\algebra`.

```
> mkdir maxim\main maxim\algebra
> dir
2019-08-14  12:39    <DIR>          .
2019-08-14  12:39    <DIR>          ..
2019-08-14  12:39    <DIR>          maxim

> dir maxim
2019-08-14  12:39    <DIR>          .
2019-08-14  12:39    <DIR>          ..
2019-08-14  12:41    <DIR>          algebra
2019-08-14  12:46    <DIR>          main

>
```

We create two classes, `Main.java` with the filename `maxim\main\Main.java` and the following content:

```
package maxim.main;

import maxim.algebra.Algebra;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        Algebra algebra = new Algebra();
        System.out.println(algebra.sayHello() + " World");
    }
}
```

and `Algebra.java` with the filename `maxim\algebra\Algebra.java` and the following content:

```
package maxim.algebra;

public class Algebra {
    public String sayHello() {
        return "Hello";
    }
}
```

Without having changed active directory, we compile the two classes, `Algebra` first:

```
> javac -cp . maxim\algebra\Algebra.java maxim\main\Main.java

>
```

We specify `-cp .` to override any `CLASSPATH` environment variable that may be set.

After the compile the directory structure looks like this:

```
.\
  maxim\
    main\
      Main.class
      Main.java
    algebra\
      Algebra.class
      Algebra.java
```

Now we can run the `Main` class:

```
> java -cp . maxim.main.Main
Hello World

>
```

Comment: It all worked up to the point when I have to compile Main.java from maxim folder.
The error says: 
package maxim.algebra does not exist

Comment: Ok. Try with `javac -cp . maxim\main\Main.java`. And if it succeeds, `java -cp . maxim.main.Main`

Comment: You say "compile Main.java from maxim folder". Do you mean you change to that directory (maxim) before you run the command?