# Compiling through Ubuntu Terminal (On Windows 10)

Tags: compiler-errors, compiler-construction, antlr, antlr4

I'm doing a course on compiler techniques. I have created a g4 format file, and will compile it when I try to do that by using java compiler (javac), then it gives me lots of errors.

Someone who can explain what I am doing wrong?

Below I'm showing what I'm typing and what I'm doing wrong.
I tried to check, if I didn't install the antlr4, but I already did, and I am sure I did.
Did the every installation through Ubuntu application through Microsoft Store, and I am using Ubuntu terminal on Windows 10.

```
:~$ cd /mnt/c/Users/myUser/dato
:/mnt/c/Users/myUser/dato$ antlr4 dato.g4
:/mnt/c/Users/myUser/dato$ javac *.java
datoBaseListener.java:3: error: package org.antlr.v4.runtime does not exist
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.ParserRuleContext;
                           ^
datoBaseListener.java:4: error: package org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree does not exist
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.ErrorNode;
                                ^
datoBaseListener.java:5: error: package org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree does not exist
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.TerminalNode;
                                ^
datoListener.java:2: error: package org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree does not exist
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.ParseTreeListener;
                                ^
datoListener.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
public interface datoListener extends ParseTreeListener {
                                      ^
  symbol: class ParseTreeListener
datoParser.java:3: error: package org.antlr.v4.runtime.dfa does not exist
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.dfa.DFA;
                               ^
datoParser.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
public class datoParser extends Parser {
                                ^
  symbol: class Parser
datoParser.java:92: error: cannot find symbol
        public static class StartContext extends ParserRuleContext {
                                                 ^
  symbol:   class ParserRuleContext
  location: class datoParser
datoBaseListener.java:31: error: cannot find symbol
        @Override public void enterEveryRule(ParserRuleContext ctx) { }
                                             ^
  symbol:   class ParserRuleContext
  location: class datoBaseListener
datoBaseListener.java:37: error: cannot find symbol
        @Override public void exitEveryRule(ParserRuleContext ctx) { }
                                            ^
  symbol:   class ParserRuleContext
  location: class datoBaseListener
datoBaseListener.java:43: error: cannot find symbol
        @Override public void visitTerminal(TerminalNode node) { }
                                            ^
  symbol:   class TerminalNode
  location: class datoBaseListener
datoBaseListener.java:49: error: cannot find symbol
        @Override public void visitErrorNode(ErrorNode node) { }
                                             ^
  symbol:   class ErrorNode
  location: class datoBaseListener
datoParser.java:93: error: cannot find symbol
                public Token d;
                       ^
  symbol:   class Token
  location: class StartContext
datoParser.java:94: error: cannot find symbol
                public TerminalNode EOF() { return getToken(datoParser.EOF, 0); }
                       ^
  symbol:   class TerminalNode
  location: class StartContext
datoParser.java:95: error: cannot find symbol
                public TerminalNode MYTOKEN() { return getToken(datoParser.MYTOKEN, 0); }
                       ^
  symbol:   class TerminalNode
  location: class StartContext
datoParser.java:96: error: cannot find symbol
                public StartContext(ParserRuleContext parent, int invokingState) {
                                    ^
  symbol:   class ParserRuleContext
  location: class StartContext
datoParser.java:101: error: cannot find symbol
                public void enterRule(ParseTreeListener listener) {
                                      ^
  symbol:   class ParseTreeListener
  location: class StartContext
datoParser.java:105: error: cannot find symbol
                public void exitRule(ParseTreeListener listener) {
                                     ^
  symbol:   class ParseTreeListener
  location: class StartContext
datoParser.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
        protected static final DFA[] _decisionToDFA;
                               ^
  symbol:   class DFA
  location: class datoParser
datoParser.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
        protected static final PredictionContextCache _sharedContextCache =
                               ^
  symbol:   class PredictionContextCache
  location: class datoParser
datoParser.java:43: error: cannot find symbol
        public static final Vocabulary VOCABULARY = new VocabularyImpl(_LITERAL_NAMES, _SYMBOLIC_NAMES);
                            ^
  symbol:   class Vocabulary
  location: class datoParser
datoParser.java:72: error: cannot find symbol
        public Vocabulary getVocabulary() {
               ^
  symbol:   class Vocabulary
  location: class datoParser
datoParser.java:86: error: cannot find symbol
        public ATN getATN() { return _ATN; }
               ^
  symbol:   class ATN
  location: class datoParser
datoParser.java:88: error: cannot find symbol
        public datoParser(TokenStream input) {
                          ^
  symbol:   class TokenStream
  location: class datoParser
datoParser.java:110: error: cannot find symbol
        public final StartContext start() throws RecognitionException {
                                                 ^
  symbol:   class RecognitionException
  location: class datoParser
datoParser.java:137: error: cannot find symbol
        public static final ATN _ATN =
                            ^
  symbol:   class ATN
  location: class datoParser
datoParser.java:2: error: package org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn does not exist
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.*;
^
datoParser.java:4: error: package org.antlr.v4.runtime does not exist
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.*;
^
datoParser.java:5: error: package org.antlr.v4.runtime.misc does not exist
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.misc.*;
^
datoParser.java:6: error: package org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree does not exist
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.*;
^
datoLexer.java:2: error: package org.antlr.v4.runtime does not exist
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.Lexer;
                           ^
datoLexer.java:3: error: package org.antlr.v4.runtime does not exist
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.CharStream;
                           ^
datoLexer.java:4: error: package org.antlr.v4.runtime does not exist
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.Token;
                           ^
datoLexer.java:5: error: package org.antlr.v4.runtime does not exist
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.TokenStream;
                           ^
datoLexer.java:8: error: package org.antlr.v4.runtime.dfa does not exist
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.dfa.DFA;
                               ^
datoLexer.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
public class datoLexer extends Lexer {
                               ^
  symbol: class Lexer
datoLexer.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
        protected static final DFA[] _decisionToDFA;
                               ^
  symbol:   class DFA
  location: class datoLexer
datoLexer.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
        protected static final PredictionContextCache _sharedContextCache =
                               ^
  symbol:   class PredictionContextCache
  location: class datoLexer
datoLexer.java:50: error: cannot find symbol
        public static final Vocabulary VOCABULARY = new VocabularyImpl(_LITERAL_NAMES, _SYMBOLIC_NAMES);
                            ^
  symbol:   class Vocabulary
  location: class datoLexer
datoLexer.java:79: error: cannot find symbol
        public Vocabulary getVocabulary() {
               ^
  symbol:   class Vocabulary
  location: class datoLexer
datoLexer.java:84: error: cannot find symbol
        public datoLexer(CharStream input) {
                         ^
  symbol:   class CharStream
  location: class datoLexer
datoLexer.java:105: error: cannot find symbol
        public ATN getATN() { return _ATN; }
               ^
  symbol:   class ATN
  location: class datoLexer
datoLexer.java:136: error: cannot find symbol
        public static final ATN _ATN =
                            ^
  symbol:   class ATN
  location: class datoLexer
datoLexer.java:6: error: package org.antlr.v4.runtime does not exist
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.*;
^
datoLexer.java:7: error: package org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn does not exist
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.*;
^
datoLexer.java:9: error: package org.antlr.v4.runtime.misc does not exist
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.misc.*;
^
datoBaseListener.java:31: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
        @Override public void enterEveryRule(ParserRuleContext ctx) { }
        ^
datoBaseListener.java:37: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
        @Override public void exitEveryRule(ParserRuleContext ctx) { }
        ^
datoBaseListener.java:43: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
        @Override public void visitTerminal(TerminalNode node) { }
        ^
datoBaseListener.java:49: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
        @Override public void visitErrorNode(ErrorNode node) { }
        ^
datoParser.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
        static { RuntimeMetaData.checkVersion("4.7.2", RuntimeMetaData.VERSION); }
                                                       ^
  symbol:   variable RuntimeMetaData
  location: class datoParser
datoParser.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
        static { RuntimeMetaData.checkVersion("4.7.2", RuntimeMetaData.VERSION); }
                 ^
  symbol:   variable RuntimeMetaData
  location: class datoParser
datoParser.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
                new PredictionContextCache();
                    ^
  symbol:   class PredictionContextCache
  location: class datoParser
datoParser.java:43: error: cannot find symbol
        public static final Vocabulary VOCABULARY = new VocabularyImpl(_LITERAL_NAMES, _SYMBOLIC_NAMES);
                                                        ^
  symbol:   class VocabularyImpl
  location: class datoParser
datoParser.java:64: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
        @Override
        ^
datoParser.java:70: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
        @Override
        ^
datoParser.java:76: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
        @Override
        ^
datoParser.java:79: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
        @Override
        ^
datoParser.java:82: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
        @Override
        ^
datoParser.java:85: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
        @Override
        ^
datoParser.java:90: error: cannot find symbol
                _interp = new ParserATNSimulator(this,_ATN,_decisionToDFA,_sharedContextCache);
                ^
  symbol:   variable _interp
  location: class datoParser
datoParser.java:90: error: cannot find symbol
                _interp = new ParserATNSimulator(this,_ATN,_decisionToDFA,_sharedContextCache);
                              ^
  symbol:   class ParserATNSimulator
  location: class datoParser
datoParser.java:94: error: cannot find symbol
                public TerminalNode EOF() { return getToken(datoParser.EOF, 0); }
                                                                      ^
  symbol:   variable EOF
  location: class datoParser
datoParser.java:95: error: cannot find symbol
                public TerminalNode MYTOKEN() { return getToken(datoParser.MYTOKEN, 0); }
                                                       ^
  symbol:   method getToken(int,int)
  location: class StartContext
datoParser.java:99: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
                @Override public int getRuleIndex() { return RULE_start; }
                ^
datoParser.java:100: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
                @Override
                ^
datoParser.java:104: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
                @Override
                ^
datoParser.java:111: error: cannot find symbol
                StartContext _localctx = new StartContext(_ctx, getState());
                                                          ^
  symbol:   variable _ctx
  location: class datoParser
datoParser.java:111: error: cannot find symbol
                StartContext _localctx = new StartContext(_ctx, getState());
                                                                ^
  symbol:   method getState()
  location: class datoParser
datoParser.java:112: error: cannot find symbol
                enterRule(_localctx, 0, RULE_start);
                ^
  symbol:   method enterRule(StartContext,int,int)
  location: class datoParser
datoParser.java:114: error: cannot find symbol
                        enterOuterAlt(_localctx, 1);
                        ^
  symbol:   method enterOuterAlt(StartContext,int)
  location: class datoParser
datoParser.java:116: error: cannot find symbol
                        setState(2);
                        ^
  symbol:   method setState(int)
  location: class datoParser
datoParser.java:117: error: cannot find symbol
                        ((StartContext)_localctx).d = match(MYTOKEN);
                                                      ^
  symbol:   method match(int)
  location: class datoParser
datoParser.java:118: error: cannot find symbol
                        setState(3);
                        ^
  symbol:   method setState(int)
  location: class datoParser
datoParser.java:119: error: cannot find symbol
                        match(EOF);
                              ^
  symbol:   variable EOF
  location: class datoParser
datoParser.java:122: error: cannot find symbol
                catch (RecognitionException re) {
                       ^
  symbol:   class RecognitionException
  location: class datoParser
datoParser.java:123: error: cannot find symbol
                        _localctx.exception = re;
                                 ^
  symbol:   variable exception
  location: variable _localctx of type StartContext
datoParser.java:124: error: cannot find symbol
                        _errHandler.reportError(this, re);
                        ^
  symbol:   variable _errHandler
  location: class datoParser
datoParser.java:125: error: cannot find symbol
                        _errHandler.recover(this, re);
                        ^
  symbol:   variable _errHandler
  location: class datoParser
datoParser.java:128: error: cannot find symbol
                        exitRule();
                        ^
  symbol:   method exitRule()
  location: class datoParser
datoParser.java:138: error: cannot find symbol
                new ATNDeserializer().deserialize(_serializedATN.toCharArray());
                    ^
  symbol:   class ATNDeserializer
  location: class datoParser
datoParser.java:140: error: cannot find symbol
                _decisionToDFA = new DFA[_ATN.getNumberOfDecisions()];
                                     ^
  symbol:   class DFA
  location: class datoParser
datoParser.java:142: error: cannot find symbol
                        _decisionToDFA[i] = new DFA(_ATN.getDecisionState(i), i);
                                                ^
  symbol:   class DFA
  location: class datoParser
datoLexer.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
        static { RuntimeMetaData.checkVersion("4.7.2", RuntimeMetaData.VERSION); }
                                                       ^
  symbol:   variable RuntimeMetaData
  location: class datoLexer
datoLexer.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
        static { RuntimeMetaData.checkVersion("4.7.2", RuntimeMetaData.VERSION); }
                 ^
  symbol:   variable RuntimeMetaData
  location: class datoLexer
datoLexer.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
                new PredictionContextCache();
                    ^
  symbol:   class PredictionContextCache
  location: class datoLexer
datoLexer.java:50: error: cannot find symbol
        public static final Vocabulary VOCABULARY = new VocabularyImpl(_LITERAL_NAMES, _SYMBOLIC_NAMES);
                                                        ^
  symbol:   class VocabularyImpl
  location: class datoLexer
datoLexer.java:71: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
        @Override
        ^
datoLexer.java:77: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
        @Override
        ^
datoLexer.java:86: error: cannot find symbol
                _interp = new LexerATNSimulator(this,_ATN,_decisionToDFA,_sharedContextCache);
                ^
  symbol:   variable _interp
  location: class datoLexer
datoLexer.java:86: error: cannot find symbol
                _interp = new LexerATNSimulator(this,_ATN,_decisionToDFA,_sharedContextCache);
                              ^
  symbol:   class LexerATNSimulator
  location: class datoLexer
datoLexer.java:89: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
        @Override
        ^
datoLexer.java:92: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
        @Override
        ^
datoLexer.java:95: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
        @Override
        ^
datoLexer.java:98: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
        @Override
        ^
datoLexer.java:101: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
        @Override
        ^
datoLexer.java:104: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
        @Override
        ^
datoLexer.java:137: error: cannot find symbol
                new ATNDeserializer().deserialize(_serializedATN.toCharArray());
                    ^
  symbol:   class ATNDeserializer
  location: class datoLexer
datoLexer.java:139: error: cannot find symbol
                _decisionToDFA = new DFA[_ATN.getNumberOfDecisions()];
                                     ^
  symbol:   class DFA
  location: class datoLexer
datoLexer.java:141: error: cannot find symbol
                        _decisionToDFA[i] = new DFA(_ATN.getDecisionState(i), i);
                                                ^
  symbol:   class DFA
  location: class datoLexer
100 errors
:/mnt/c/Users/myUser/dato$ sudo apt install antlr4
[sudo] password for ACCOUNT:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
antlr4 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
:/mnt/c/Users/myUser/dato$
```

Why am I getting these errors? Am I using a wrong command?

Comment: Code blocks should be used for console output (and for most program text as well, unless your code can actually be run within the brower). Use the `{}` button to create a code block, or just put three backtics before and after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Java compiler cannot find the ANTLR runtime classes (this is the meaning of the `error: package org.antlr.v4.runtime does not exist` error). In other words, the classes in `antlr-4.8-complete.jar` [are not properly added to your CLASSPATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2396493/what-is-a-classpath-and-how-do-i-set-it).

Forget about any aliases for these commands: learn how to compile Java classes yourself.

First make sure the files `antlr-4.8-complete.jar` and `dato.g4` are in the same folder, and open a terminal and CD into this folder.

### 1 generate the parser

```
java -cp antlr-4.8-complete.jar org.antlr.v4.Tool dato.g4
```

### 2 compile Java files

Windows

```
javac -cp .;antlr-4.8-complete.jar *.java
```

*nix

```
javac -cp .:antlr-4.8-complete.jar *.java
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help :-) Was searching for that.

Comment: By the way, I noticed that when I looked into the folder, it looked like the folder was already compiled before this. But can it compile even if it gives errors in the terminal?

Comment: Only classes could have compiled that did not have any ANTLR imports (so no `import org.antlr...`). If there are `.class` files that conained such imports, it means that the ANTLR jar was part of your CLASSPATH (temporarily). Most likely you added it to the CLASSPATH in a terminal and that terminal window was closed.