# Difference between classpath:/some/packages vs file:/some/url when configuring Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm learning Spring Boot and sometimes I have to config application.properties with values like `classpath:/some/packages` and `file:/some/url`. What is the difference between classpath vs file in this situation ?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to understand what the classpath is. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2396759/992940) is a good answer about it:

> It would be impractical to have the VM look through every folder on your machine, so you have to provide the VM a list of places to look. This is done by putting folder and jar files on your classpath.

Shortly, classpaths contain:

- JAR files of your project
- and Paths to the top of package hierarchies.

So when you have `classpath:/some/packages` - think of it as you point to a file inside your project (the first `/` is the root for the compiled classes and resources). But when you have `file:/some/url` you point to a file anywhere in the OS.