# Cannot open particular JAR file for Salesforce JDBC Driver

Tags: jdbc, jar, salesforce

I have no issues with opening other JARs but I cannot open 2 JARs with 2 Salesforce JDBC drivers.

When I double click on it, nothing happens. If I use 'java -jar jar_file_name.jar', there is an error 'no main manifest attribute'. And this is not my Java code, that's just JAR, so I cannot add this main manifest attribute. Please let me know what I can do to open such files and to use Salesforce JDBC drivers without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

A main manifest attribute is only needed for an executable Java **application**. A JDBC driver JAR is a **library**, and as such doesn't need to be executable<sup>1</sup>. Trying to run a JDBC driver using `java -jar <jdbc-driver.jar>` is not normal.

Instead, you need to add the JAR file to the class path of the application you're using. How exactly you add a JAR file to the class path depends on the application that needs to use the library, check its documentation.

See also [What is a classpath and how do I set it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2396493/what-is-a-classpath-and-how-do-i-set-it)

---

<sup>1) some JDBC drivers do have a main manifest attribute, but that either runs a small program informing you that you shouldn't run the driver, but add it to a class path, or provides a simple diagnostic tool</sup>