# Why does my JSONParser throw NoClassDefFoundError?

Tags: java, json, json-simple

I'm trying to convert scanner string into JSONObject in Java and import JSON modules from Json Simple. I have already added JSON-simple-1.1.1.jar into my build path. However, when I was trying to paser my inline string.
My inline string looks like this: **{"events":[{"url":"/manipulate-cloudy-country","visitorId":"03c0b5e0-3eeb-382a-8c6d-35e4bb189cf6","timestamp":1515042087205},...{
"url":"/race-lazy-control",
"visitorId":"0832d11b-017a-388a-8a9e-77e5a1f6f9f4",
"timestamp":1515042342655
}]}**
It should be a bunch of data that I try to convert into JSONObject.

The complier shows:
**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/simple/JSONObject
at Solution.main(Solution.java:45)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json.simple.JSONObject
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
... 1 more**

How can I fix it, or is there any better solution to convert it? Please help me!

````
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Scanner;

import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;

public class Solution {
public static void main(String[] args) {
try {
        //URL url = new URL(
                    "My API");
        /**
        *{"events":[{"url":"/manipulate-cloudy-country","visitorId":"03c0b5e0-3eeb-382a-8c6d-35e4bb189cf6","timestamp":1515042087205},...{"url":"/shoe-boundless-curtain","visitorId":"e367b3c8-3d48-345d-937c-0c4f6cce216a","timestamp":1515042137934},{"url":"/race-lazy-control","visitorId":"0832d11b-017a-388a-8a9e-77e5a1f6f9f4","timestamp":1515042342655}]}
        **/
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.connect();

            int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
            if (responseCode != 200) {
                throw new RuntimeException("HttpResponseCode: " + responseCode);
            } else {
                String inline = "";
                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(url.openStream());
                while (scanner.hasNext()) {
                    inline += scanner.nextLine();
                }
                // Close the scanner
                scanner.close();

                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
                JSONParser p = new JSONParser();
                p.parse(inline);


            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } ```
````

Comment: Make sure your org.json dependency is compiled into the final jar

Answer (score 0):

Your problem has nothing to do with JSON parsing, it's about how to use a Java library.

The code you posted shows that you're importing classes like `org.json.simple.JSONObject` which are not part of the Java standard library, hence you need to provide them to the Java runtime, usually by including the **jar**, which is basically a zip file containing class files (`.class` files, the compiled version of a `.java` file), into the so-called **classpath**, which is where the Java runtime looks for classes to load.

Here's an example of how you could run your program in case you already had the simple-json jar at `libs/simple-json.jar`, and you already compiled your `Solution` class:

```
java -cp libs/simple-json.jar Solution
```

With this, the Java runtime will find the JSON classes inside the jar and everything should work.

If you need more jars in the classpath, you can separate them using `:` on Mac/Linux or `;` on Windows.

For example:

```
java -cp libs/simple-json.jar:libs/other-lib.jar Solution
```

For detailed information about how this works, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2396759/1007991).