# In the context of Maven dependencies, how do I make sense of classpaths and their effect on execution?

Tags: java, maven, build, dependencies, classpath

I understand that ...

1. in Java, [classpaths are environment variables that JVM needs during compilation to locate used classes, packages, and other resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2396493/what-is-a-classpath-and-how-do-i-set-it)
2. in Maven, phases are processes that are constituents of Maven's build lifecycles
3. in Maven, [a dependency’s dependency is referred to as a transitive dependency](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Dependency_Version_Requirement_Specification)
4. in Maven, [a dependency's scope "refers to the classpath of the task at hand and sets the dependency’s transitivity"](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Dependency_Version_Requirement_Specification)

I don't really understand the meaning of the third statement. **Is it that the scope defines the classpaths in which the dependency is available?**

More importantly, ...

1. **how do I relate a dependency's scope (classpaths) to its transitivity?**
2. **how do I relate a dependency's scope (classpaths) to the project's phases and their execution?**

Answer (score 0):

First in Java an environment variable `CLASSPATH` can be defined but you can also use the command line option `java -cp ..` instead.

In general you have two scopes `compile` and `test`. The compile scope is the one used by default if no scope is defined. That usually defines the dependencies which are needed to build your parts (compiling!) for production code (`src/main/java`).

The `test` scope defines the dependencies which are only used for running/compiling your tests.

This means while building with Maven there are two different classpaths one for production code and one for testing. If you build via `mvn verify -X` and take a deep look into the debugging output you can see those different parts something like this:

```
[DEBUG] test classpath:  /Users/khm/ws-git-soebes/katas/fraction/target/test-classes
/Users/khm/ws-git-soebes/katas/fraction/target/classes  
/Users/khm/.m2/repository/org/apiguardian/apiguardian-api/1.1.2/apiguardian-api-1.1.2.jar  
/Users/khm/.m2/repository/org/junit/jupiter/junit-jupiter-api/5.8.2/junit-jupiter-api-5.8.2.jar
```

The first entry contains the `target/test-classes` that means everything what is in your `src/test/java` directory is first on your test classpath. Afterwards you will see `target/class` which contains the production code (`src/main/java`) and afterwards you see `apiguardian-api-1.1.2.jar` which is `compile` scope dependency and after that you will see all `test` scope dependencies.

You can see also the for the compiling of the production code the output looks like this:

```
[DEBUG] Classpath:
[DEBUG]  /Users/khm/ws-git-soebes/katas/fraction/target/classes
[DEBUG]  /Users/khm/.m2/repository/org/apiguardian/apiguardian-api/1.1.2/apiguardian-api-1.1.2.jar
[DEBUG] Source roots:
[DEBUG]  /Users/khm/ws-git-soebes/katas/fraction/src/main/java
[DEBUG]  /Users/khm/ws-git-soebes/katas/fraction/target/generated-sources/annotations
[DEBUG] Command line options:
[DEBUG] -d /Users/khm/ws-git-soebes/katas/fraction/target/classes -classpath /Users/khm/ws-git-soebes/katas/fraction/target/classes:/Users/khm/.m2/repository/org/apiguardian/apiguardian-api/1.1.2/apiguardian-api-1.1.2.jar: -sourcepath /Users/khm/ws-git-soebes/katas/fraction/src/main/java:/Users/khm/ws-git-soebes/katas/fraction/target/generated-sources/annotations: -s /Users/khm/ws-git-soebes/katas/fraction/target/generated-sources/annotations -g -nowarn --release 11 -encoding UTF-8 -Xlint:deprecation -Xlint:unchecked
```

This shows `target/classes` which contains the compiled class of your own parts from `src/main/java` and and entry `apiguardian-api-1.1.2.jar` which is a dependency scope: `compile` (`apiguardian-api-1.1.2.jar`).

So the scope defines where a dependency can be seen (or more accurate to be used).

> how do I relate a dependency's scope (classpaths) to its transitivity?

A `compile` scope dependency of your own project would be propageted to another project which is using your project.
A `test` scope dependency in contradiction is not propagated to other projects.

[More detailed in pom explanations](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#dependencies)

> how do I relate a dependency's scope (classpaths) to the project's phases and their execution?

Usually a `compile` scope is related to the compile phase (+testing of course) and the `test` scope is related to the test phase (unit- testing via maven-surefire-plugin or integration testing via maven-failsafe-plugin).