# mounting secrets in Openshift

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, openshift

I'm trying to move java SpringBoot application to Openshift.
I have keystore file defined in the application.yaml like this:

```
platform:
  messaging:
    mq:
      keystore-path: classpath:certificates/spid_S116807_T.p12
      keystore-password: xxx
      keystore-type: pkcs12
```

I thought if I create volumemount and secret like this I could use the keystore. lapc-spid contains spid_S116807_T.p12.

```
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /certificates
              name: lapc-spid-n3jcy
              readOnly: true
```

```
      volumes:
        - name: lapc-spid-n3jcy
          secret:
            defaultMode: 420
            secretName: lapc-spid
```

Unfortunatley I get the following error:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [certificates/spid_S116807_T.p12] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: jar:file:/cs/app/app.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/certificates/spid_S116807_T.p12
```

What am I missing here? How can I mount the secret to my container?

Comment: That looks like the correct way to mount. Are you sure `/` is part your service's classpath?

Comment: sorry, I don't get it. how can I check it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2396493/1032785

Comment: If I had to guess based on your output, I would try mounting `/cs/app/certificates`

Comment: unfortunately I get the same error

Comment: Do the rsh to the pod and check if the p12 mounted  under /certificates. Also is /certificates is in your classpath because as per error it’s looking p12 under /cs/app/app.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/certificates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it would be useful for someone.

I modified the application.yaml configuration like this:

```
platform:
  messaging:
    mq:
      keystore-path: file:/p12/spid_S116807_T.p12
      keystore-password: xxx
      keystore-type: pkcs12
```

and I mounted it to folder p12

```
  volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /p12
      name: lapc-spid-a168z
      readOnly: true

  volumes:
    - name: lapc-spid-a168z
      secret:
        defaultMode: 420
        secretName: lapc-spid
```

and it works.