# Encountering a Mysql Connection problem java

Tags: java, ubuntu

The error I am getting is PY4JAVAERROR :

```
an error occurred while calling o313.load: Java.lang.classnotfoundexception: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

has anyone encountered this before?

[image]

Comment: this is not a MySQL connection error. The driver just isn't on your classpath

Comment: Hi Stultuske, my mysql-connector is present in /usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar and i have called it in the spark query.

Comment: what do you think "ClassNotFoundException signifies"?

Comment: I am not using classes, I have attached a picture to my original post to illustrate the way im attempting.

Comment: The fact the driver is in /usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar does not mean it is on the classpath of your application. And you definitely are using classes. What do you think `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` is?

Comment: @PaulCorcoran you are "not using classes"? Are you being serious?

Comment: apologies, I meant explicitly using class: to create this. I understand that under the hood it is using classes. I have called the driver in the spark.read.format in the query so I am at a loss to what is going wrong and where. It is a bit out of the comfort zone.

Comment: @PaulCorcoran the problem is, you are trying to use that class, and it's not on the classpath

Answer (score 0):

Place mysql-connector jar in your classpath.

Answer (score 0):

That **occurs when you don't have a MySQL connector** in your classpath. If you are using a maven project you can try adding the dependency to your pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

If you are not using a dependency management tool like Maven or Gradle you can download the jar online and then add it to your classpath. Here is the link.
https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/

Remember to do a bit of research for the correct versions before you download.
Either of the two options will definitely work.

Comment: thank yoiu @AmohPrice, I have downloaded the connector for ubunut 20.04 on that link and it seems to have installed on my os. when you say add it to your classpath what do you mean?

Comment: Hey @PaulCorcoran . Look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2396493/what-is-a-classpath-and-how-do-i-set-it) read the answers you will definitely understand.

Comment: @PaulCorcoran if you don't understand it. A dependency management tool like Maven or Gradle will help you out because it does the downloading and adding to your classpath. so if you do not want to do the hard work. Think about it.

Answer (score -1):

It seems the `mysql` connectivity library is not included in the project. Solve the problem following one of the proposed solutions:

MAVEN PROJECTS SOLUTION
Add the `mysql-connector` `dependency` to the `pom.xml` project file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.39</version> // your desired version
</dependency>
```

***Here you are all the versions:*** https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java

ALL PROJECTS SOLUTION
Add the jar library manually to the project.

```
Right Click the project -- > build path -- > configure build path
```

In **Libraries** Tab press Add **`External Jar`** `and Select your jar`.

You can find zip for mysql-connector [here](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/5.0.html)

**Explanation**:
When building the project, java throws you an exception because a file (the `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver class`) from the `mysql` connectivity library is not found. The solution is adding the library to the project, and java will find the `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`

Comment: You shouldn't automatically assume maven is being used

Comment: Yes, you are right, but it could be possible, that's why I mentioned both. Thanks for highlighting this.

Comment: I am using ubuntu and have installed the mysqlconnector jar, I seem to be missing the driver set up which is what seems to be my problem. thank you for your answer

Comment: Please accept the most relevant answer If this solve your question.

Comment: its helped me understand that it is the jdbc driver that is missing but I still have issues adding to project. I am using ubuntu with pyspark jupiter notebooks