# Java packaging issues

Tags: java, classnotfoundexception

Based on java documentation, I've set up my project as such:
Source files are in `C:\...\sources\com\myname\tictactoe\`
And my class files are in `C:\...\classes\com\myname\tictactoe\`
When I try to run a class (`Main.java`) in that directory (on powershell) by running "`java Main`", I get "`Error: Could not find or load main class Main Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Main`". All my files start with "`package com.myname.tictactoe;`", and from what I understand that's how they're supposed to be. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Main.java is the source file, not the classfile

Comment: what happens when you run `java -cp . com.myname.tictactoe.Main` in the `classes` folder?

Comment: have you set the classpath somewhere? If not then check this out .. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2396493/what-is-a-classpath-and-how-do-i-set-it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change directory to `C:\...\classes` then run

```
java -cp . com/myname/tictactoe/Main
```

Comment: Worked! Ty. Just had to insert an extra com/ before the myname directory :)

Comment: Yes it should be full package path, I corrected it

Answer (score 2):

Your java class has a package name so you will not be able to run just java Main.  You will need to run java com.myname.tictactoe.Main.