# Visual studio code cannot find java libraries

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, lwjgl, lib

I've setup a Java project in Visual Studio Code. I installed previously a few java extensions :

[image: Extensions]

and I can create a program that does Hello World.
In a folder called lib inside the project folder, I copied some jars (lwjgl3) and, although are shown by intellisense when I try to import them, I have an error that says it cannot find the package :

[image: Error]

Anything I missed ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the jar to your classpath.  The classpath is something used by java to find the libraries your program uses.  Java looks in each folder/jar archive to find the class files, because it would be slow if it searched every directory on your computer.  See this question: [What is a classpath and how do I set it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2396493/what-is-a-classpath-and-how-do-i-set-it)

Answer (score 0):

Add a reference to the package in the following way.

- Click the plus sign to the right of **Referenced Libraries** under the **JAVA PROJECTS** panel

  [image]
- Select the `.jar` file in the pop-up window.