# Java in vscode can't import classes from other files: compilation failed (probably because of CodeRunner extension)

Tags: java, class, import

Im trying to create two classes in separated files and then use all of them in just one file:

- The first class is "Main" as follows:

```java
package com.rafa.test;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Primitive Data Types
        byte myByte = 127;
        short myShort = 32767;
        int myInt = 2147483647;
        long myLong = 9223372036854775807L; // Note the 'L' suffix for long literals
        float myFloat = 3.14f; // Note the 'f' suffix for float literals
        double myDouble = 3.141592653589793;
        char myChar = 'A';
        boolean myBoolean = true;

        // Reference Data Types
        String myString = "Hello, Java!";
        int[] myArray = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }; // Array of integers
        Object myObject = new Object(); // An instance of the Object class
        Integer myInteger = 45;
        
        // Log all variables
        System.out.println(
            "myByte: " + myByte +
            "\nmyShort: " + myShort +
            "\nmyInt: " + myInt +
            "\nmyLong: " + myLong +
            "\nmyFloat: " + myFloat +
            "\nmyDouble: " + myDouble +
            "\nmyChar: " + myChar +
            "\nmyBoolean: " + myBoolean +
            "\nmyString: " + myString +
            "\nmyArray: " + Arrays.toString(myArray) +
            "\nmyObject: " + myObject +
            "\nmyInteger: " + myInteger
        );

        sayMessage();

        MyClass classe = new MyClass();
        classe.notAConstructor();

    }

    private static void sayMessage() {
        System.out.println("This method worked !");
    }
}
```

- The second class is "MyClass" as follows:

```java
package com.rafa.test;

public class MyClass {
    public void notAConstructor() {
        System.out.println("I've been called !");
    }
}
```

However, when i add this line in my code: "MyClass classe = new MyClass();", i get this error:

```
Main.java:45: error: cannot find symbol
        MyClass classe = new MyClass();
        ^
  symbol:   class MyClass
  location: class Main
Main.java:45: error: cannot find symbol
        MyClass classe = new MyClass();
                             ^
  symbol:   class MyClass
  location: class Main
2 errors
error: compilation failed
```

Or even this line "import com.rafa.test.MyClass;" in the top of my code, i get one more error:

```
Main.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
import com.rafa.test.MyClass;
```

- Here is my Folder structure:

```
com
|-- rafa
|   |-- test
|       |-- Main.java
|       |-- MyClass.java
|       |-- MyClass.class
|       |-- Main.class
```

I expect to resolve the issue by successfully importing my class "MyClass" in the Main file, and use it.
Im using VSCODE, with these java extesions: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-java-pack

+ CodeRunner with this configuration

```json
"code-runner.executorMap": {
    "java": "cls ; cd $dir && javac *.java && java $fileName",
  },
```

I also realized that the code runs perfectly without code runner. So the problem might be with the configuration of codeRunner extension. If anyone can figure out what i need to change in the configuration of codeRunner i would be very thankful.

Comment: Where did the `code-runner.executorMap` comes from? Is this generated by the VSCode extension?

Comment: try to delete top package declaration for `cls ; cd $dir && javac *.java && java $fileName`

Answer (score 0):

The `code-runner.executorMap` looks a bit suspicious. Especially the part `java $fileName`. I assume this should start your Java program. But this command misses the classpath argument. Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/2396759/6044791 for an explanation of the classpath argument. In short the classpath is necessary so the JVM can find all referenced class files.

As you have already noted you added the `import com.rafa.test.MyClass;`. This is mandatory if want to access any class located outside another class. But w/o setting the classpath this will raise the `cannot find symbol`-error either.

Comment: There are dozens of tutorials about java classpath. Here is one I found https://dev.to/martingaston/understanding-the-java-classpath-building-a-project-manually-3c3l.