# Problems with manually created packages

Tags: java, package

**Problem Context:**

I have a manually created java "project", independent of any IDEs that has a directory structure like this:

[image: project directory]

Inside number\ there is a file called IntegerFour.java
Inside tester\ there is a file called EncryptTest.java

I have assigned a package to the IntegerFour.java file with the package statement:
`package number;`

I have assigned a package to the EncryptTest.java file with the package statement:
`package tester;`

Now inside EncryptTest.java I have imported the IntegerFour class with the statement:
`import number.IntegerFour;`

IntegerFour.java:

```java
package number;

public class IntegerFour
{
    IntegerFour(){}

}
```

EncryptTest.java

```java
package tester;
import number.IntegerFour;

public class EncryptTest
{
    
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        
        IntegerFour userNum = new IntegerFour();

    }

}
```

Terminal:

```
PS C:\Users\hunkh> cd C:\Users\hunkh\OneDrive\Desktop\project
PS C:\Users\hunkh\OneDrive\Desktop\project> javac .\source\number\IntegerFour.java
PS C:\Users\hunkh\OneDrive\Desktop\project> javac .\source\tester\EncryptTest.java
.\source\tester\EncryptTest.java:2: error: package number does not exist
import number.IntegerFour;
             ^
.\source\tester\EncryptTest.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
        IntegerFour userNum = new IntegerFour();
        ^
  symbol:   class IntegerFour
  location: class EncryptTest
.\source\tester\EncryptTest.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
        IntegerFour userNum = new IntegerFour();
                                  ^
  symbol:   class IntegerFour
  location: class EncryptTest
3 errors
PS C:\Users\hunkh\OneDrive\Desktop\project>
```

**Problem:**

Now, when I compile the IntegerFour.java file it compiles normally.
When I compile the EncryptTest.java file, it gives an error with the statement:
"the package 'number' does NOT exist."

**What I have tried**

I have read the official Oracle documentation for packages and read through many stack overflow articles but could not find one comprehensive guide that would help me fully understand how packages work.

Contrary to this, when i create a project using an IDE like IntelliJ and use IntelliJ itself to create a package and add files to it, everything works normally, even though the code and the directory structure is exactly the same.

The problem is that I want to share my package with someone else, so I want to do this manually without using IDEs to first get a sense of how everything works.

Also, the classes/ folder is to host the corresponding .class files (if they ever get compiled that is haha) .

I also have additional questions surrounding this topic such as:

Q1: If the package name is supposed to mirror the parent directory path, why do we not start at the root folder, for example C.Users...

Q2: If i successfully create a package, can I use it in any java file anywhere on my system? How does the scope of the package work.

Comment: Try compiling from the project "root", i.e. the `project` directory and reference the `EntryptTest` through a relative path: `javac tester/EncryptTest.java`.

Comment: Please show the commands you used to compile the files, and a [mcve] of the contents of those files.

Comment: @Turing85 Thanks for the suggestion, that did not work, as can be seen from the  terminal commands I have now included in the post.

Comment: @Sweeper Done! Please review the post now.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Please re-execute the command from directory `source`.

Comment: @Turing85 That works! But I do not understand how or what changed. Is the compilation of files dependent on where we compile it from? Clearly there is something crucial that I do not understand about the way the compiler works with files and packages. I would really appreciate it if you could refer me to relevant articles or guide me further. Cheers.

Comment: Packages correlate with directory structures (where the `.` is the directory separator, i.e. `/` on NIX-systems and `\ ` on Wondows systems). The fully qualified class name (FQCN for short) is the "path from where we   are" to the actual file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't seem to understand the idea of [class paths](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2396493/5133585). This is basically the answer to both of your questions.

*Where* Java starts looking for classes, is determined by the class path. By default, this is where you run your command, so in your case, the class path is "project". To resolve `number.IntegerFour`, `javac` would look for "project/number/IntegerFour.class. There is no such "project/number" directory, so compilation fails.

The correct class path to use here is "project/source", since "number/IntegerFour.class" is located there. You can either add the `-cp source` option, or run the command in "source" directly.

This also applies when running the class files using `java`. Make sure the class path is correct!

Since you also have a "classes" directory, IMO it is better to use `-d classes` to have the .class files generated there, then the class path would be "project/classes".

Rather than compiling each file one by one, it would be more convenient to pass all the files to `javac`. Just list all the files you want to compile and pass them to `javac`, or use the `-sourcepath` option.

Finally, `IntegerFour` should have a public constructor, so that classes from other packages can call it.