Issue with Dependency Injection in Spring Boot Application
I am facing an issue with dependency injection in my Spring Boot Application. While testing Project C, I am encountering a bean not found error for  com.project.ProjectA.repository. I have included the necessary packages in @SpringBootApplication(scanBacsePackages), but the bean is still not found. Any insight on resolving this issue?
Parameter 0 of constructor in com.project.ProjectC.AILogController required a bean of type com.project.ProjectA.service.TestingLogService that could not be found.
Consider defining a bean of type ‘projectA.TestingLogService' in your configuration.
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.project.projectA”, "com.project.ProjectB”, "com.project.ProjectC”})
public class ProjectCApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ProjectCApplication, args);
    }
}

pom.xml
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.project</groupId>
            <artifactId>projectA</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${projectA-systemPath}</systemPath>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.project</groupId>
            <artifactId>projectB</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${projectB-systemPath}</systemPath>
        </dependency>

I'm expecting to merge three spring boot projects together.
I've created jar files for com.project.ProjectA and com.project.ProjectB and added it to com.project.ProjectC.
I am able to build the project with out any errors by running the command mvn clean install. However, I'm facing errors when I attempt to run the command  mvn spring-boot:run.

Did you remember to annotate TestingLogService as @Service? If yes, then make sure it is on the classpath.

I did annotate it with @Service. What exactly do you mean by make sure its on the class path?

if it is located in a different jar you need to add that jar onto the classpath, for example by adding it as maven dependency. Otherwise it is not on the classpath and therefore won't be found. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2396493/what-is-a-classpath-and-how-do-i-set-it

I ran these command but I'm still seeing the same error.                                     export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/Users/mike/Documents/code-projects/jar/projectA-0.0.1.jar
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/Users/mike/Documents/code-projects/jar/projectB-0.0.1.jar

I also updated the pom file to include the file location in dependencies. Please see the updated post

seems all correct, but since it is still not working, something is missing. Please post ur complete pom.xml

I was able to get it working by adding the projects A and B as child projects in project C

To troubleshot this, better to have the stack trace of the exception. But there are couple of things you can check:

Does  com.project.ProjectA.service.TestingLogService is annotated with @Component or @Service?
Is com.project.ProjectA.service.TestingLogService is on the classpath?

Based on your code the first is more probable to be the culprit.
