Does JVM encompasses the JAVA SE library's binary code
As per my understanding,
*.java file convert into bytecote,*.class by executing javac.
Once JVM instantiate, JVM component JIT Compiler, converts that bytecode into binary code. and that binary code instruction eventually executed by JVM on to underlying architecture.
Based on above understanding, if i write my code by utilizing library like apache-commons, i need to pass that library jar(*.classes) while running the code.
Here question, i also use JDK inbuilt library like java.base for String class. but i never added that library while running java.
Does that means, for JDK's in-bult classes, JVM already have binary code available with it ?

JVM looks for classes in classpath. Take a look at this https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/findingclasses.html. Also related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2396493/what-is-a-classpath-and-how-do-i-set-it?noredirect=1&lq=1

@RBS No, your Comment is not quite true. Many poor Questions have good Answers. And some of those poor Questions are eventually deleted, along with any Answers good or bad.  Stack Overflow has been successful where others failed because of its specific rules defining quality.  Read the Help section to learn those rules.


Does that means, for JDK's in-bult classes, JVM already have binary code available with it ?

Generally no (for HotSpot JVMs).
First of all, the your mental model is not entirely correct.  Yes, bytecodes are typically compiled to native code1, but it happens on-the-fly.  Once a bytecode method has been called and executed by the bytecode interpreter a few times, it will be compiled to native by the JIT compiler.
The JDK's in-built classes are treated the same way.  They are loaded and interpreted in bytecode form, and then JIT compiled to native code.  Hence, the "binary" (native code) is not already available.
The bytecodes for JDK classes are part of a Java JDK or JRE installation.  (Depending on the nature of the JDK / JRE, it will either contain all of the bytecodes, or the subset required by a specific application.)  The built-in classes' bytecodes are loaded via the JVM's bootstrap classpath.  (You don't need to worry about it.)
Exceptions:

Certain JDK built-in classes have methods declared as native.  These have native code implementations, typically coded in C and C++, and provided by the java executable.
Certain JDK built-in classes have methods declared as @intrinsic.  These may be handled as special cases by the JIT compiler.
Non-JDK classes can have native methods too, but they will be implemented by a dynamically loaded native library.

But note that a lot of these details are implementation specific.  They vary between Hotspot, OpenJ9, and GraalVM implementations, and with historical and 3rd-party Java implementations.

1 - Bytecodes are binary too!  Binary is not the distinguishing property here.

i am much clear after reading this article https://www.baeldung.com/java-classloaders. As those inbuilt classes present in /jre/lib directory and loaded as part of Bootstrap classloader.

Java Virtual Machine (JVM): The JVM is a software program that executes the bytecode instructions. It's designed to be platform-independent, meaning the same bytecode can run on different operating systems as long as there's a JVM for that platform.
Just-In-Time (JIT) Compilation: While the JVM can directly interpret bytecode, modern JVMs often use a JIT compiler to improve performance. The JIT compiler translates bytecode into machine code specific to the underlying architecture (e.g., x86, ARM) at runtime. This machine code is the binary code that the CPU can directly execute.
Built-in Libraries:
Pre-installed: Classes from the standard Java libraries (like java.base for String) are included in the Java Development Kit (JDK) installation. These libraries are already in machine code format for the target architecture you're using.
Classpath: When you run a Java program, the JVM uses the classpath to locate the necessary classes. The classpath typically includes the directory containing your compiled .class files and the directories containing the standard Java libraries.
Key Points:
You don't need to explicitly include JAR files for built-in libraries because they are already part of the JDK installation.
The JVM takes care of locating the necessary classes and potentially translating the bytecode into machine code for execution.
Additional Notes:
Third-party libraries are usually distributed as JAR files. You need to include the JAR file in your classpath for the JVM to find them.
Some build tools like Maven and Gradle handle classpath management automatically.
Paraphrased Explanation of Java Compilation and Execution
Compilation and Bytecode: When you use the javac command to compile a .java file, it is transformed into bytecode, which is a platform-independent format. This bytecode is stored in a file with a .class extension. Java Virtual Machine (JVM): The JVM is a software program responsible for executing the bytecode instructions. It is designed to be platform-independent, allowing the same bytecode to run on different operating systems as long as there's a JVM for that platform. Just-In-Time (JIT) Compilation: Although the JVM can directly interpret bytecode, modern JVMs often utilize a JIT compiler to enhance performance. The JIT compiler translates bytecode into machine code specific to the underlying architecture at runtime, improving execution speed. Built-in Libraries and Classpath: Classes from the standard Java libraries, which are pre-installed in the Java Development Kit (JDK), are already in machine code format for the target architecture. When running a Java program, the JVM uses the classpath to locate the necessary classes, including the directory containing compiled .class files and the directories containing standard Java libraries. Key Points:
JAR files for built-in libraries are not required to be explicitly included as they are part of the JDK installation.
The JVM handles the process of locating necessary classes and potentially translating bytecode into machine code for execution.
