# javac: compile a java class with third-party library

Tags: javac, artifacts

I have a class that uses "org.apache.ant" and the class is very simple, it's not even in a package.

So I simply use javac MyClass.java to compile it, of course, I got this error saying package "org.apache.ant" not found.

I've downloaded the artifact.
So how do I specify the source of the library in the javac command?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use classpath to include the package after you compile.

It might look something like this...

```
javac -classpath .;org.apache.ant.jar MyClass
java -classpath .;org.apache.ant.jar MyClass
```

Refer to this link for more information.
[Help with packages in java - import does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/631682/help-with-packages-in-java-import-does-not-work)

*Update*
Following the Ant Installation tips here.
https://supportweb.cs.bham.ac.uk/docs/tutorials/docsystem/build/tutorials/ant/ant.html