# Java - Can't import com.package.*(wildcard)

Tags: java, import, classpath

This may be a simple issue, but Google has returned nothing.

I have read [Help with packages in java - import does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/631682/help-with-packages-in-java-import-does-not-work)

I still don't understand why a direct import will work but wildcard will not.
[EDIT]
By class package I mean a package of classes.  I am still new to Java so I do not know the semantics
[EDIT]

I have a class package: `com.company.functions`, when I try to `import com.company.*` I receive the following error.

```
java: package com.company does not exist
```

If I import `com.company.function` explicitly then I have no issues.

So I suppose that I have a solution but for the sake of learning, could someone explain why I see this issue?

IDE:IntelliJ IDEA 12

```
import com.sociapathy.*;  <--Throws compile error  java: package com.sociapathy does       not exist
import com.sociapathy.databaseAccess.MySQL;  <--Works just fine
```

Comment: What type of IDE you are using ?

Comment: Can you show parts of your code? It's hard to tell the context of your problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "I have a class package: `com.company.functions`" ? Is `functions` a package ?

Comment: Is `com.company` actually a package?

Comment: I have edited the question according to above comments.

Comment: Importing is not recursive.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to import a package that contains no classes, but only contains sub-packages.

i.e. You have classes in `com.company.functions` - *e.g.*  `com.company.functions.Foo`
But no classes directly in `com.company` - *e.g.* `com.company.Bar`

Despite that fact that java packages appear to be hierarchical, for the purposes of imports, they aren't.

So, you cannot import `com.company.*` because it contains no classes of its own.
You can import `com.company.functions.*` because it does contain classes
And you can import `com.company.functions.Foo` because that is a class.

Now, you might be tempted create a `Bar` class in `com.company`.
That would allow you to import `com.company.*`
**But** because imports are not treated hierarchically, that wouldn't cause classes in `com.company.functions` to be imported
You would still need to explictly import `com.company.functions.Foo`, or wildcard import `com.company.functions.*`

Answer (score 1):

In java, you can import an entire package:

```
import package.name.*;
```

Or you can import a specific member of a package

```
import package.name.class_name;
```

Don't confuse the dots in package names with the member access operator - they're just literal dots.  You can't try to import multiple packages by breaking apart the package names.

```
import package.*;  //doesn't work
import packa*;  //doesn't work for the same reason
```