# package org.apache.opennlp does not exist - play frame work adding external jars

Tags: java, apache, playframework, playframework-2.0, opennlp

I am using play frame work with Eclipse and I am trying to use opennlp for tokenization of data that is in a CSV file. So, I am uploading the CSV file and trying to tokenize it using opennlp library.

So I have added the maven dependencies in Build.scala as below, and i am trying to import the package in my Application. I see the above error. Please let me know what I what else I need to add ?

Error:

```
    ! @6fhjk1mko - Internal server error, for (GET) [/] ->

    sbt.PlayExceptions$CompilationException: Compilation error[error: package org.ap
    ache.opennlp does not exist]
            at sbt.PlayReloader$$anon$2$$anonfun$reload$2$$anonfun$apply$15$$anonfun
    $apply$16.apply(PlayReloader.scala:349) ~[na:na]
```

Application.java:

```
import opennlp.tools.*;
```

Build.scala:

```
    val appDependencies = Seq(
        // Add your project dependencies here,
        javaCore,
        javaJdbc,
        javaEbean,
        "org.apache.opennlp" % "opennlp-tools" % "1.5.3"
      )

      val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(
        // Add your own project settings here         
            resolvers += "Commons Validator" at "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-validator/commons-validator/",
            resolvers += "Maven repository repo1.maven.org" at "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2"

      )
```

Comment: Did you reload Play settings in order to load the new dependency ? Either by restarting the Play console, either by using `reload` in the Play console.

Comment: Hi nico_ekito... yes i did

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be caused by the fact that opennlp.tools doesn't have class, but only sub-packages in it. You need to import like below:

import opennlp.tools.chunker.*;

More explanations here: [java-cant-import-com-package-wildcard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16976184/1536803)