# How can I compile a class with non existing references?

Tags: java, android-runtime

I'm currently able to compile a class that has this import statement:

`import com.panframe.android.lib.*;`

But there is no external dependency which satisfies this statement. The code somehow uses this import statement. Even Android Studio warns me about this non existent class:

[image]

How I am able to compile this class? Shouldn't compiler prevent this from happening?

Comment: The import statement says "import everything from the package com.panframe.android.lib". And it does - since there is nothing in that package, it imports nothing. This is one of the reasons why using wildcard imports is not considered a good idea by many people.

Comment: I added the image directly into the post, but it would be better if you post the code itself and not an image of it.

Comment: The image doesn't contain anything concerning the import or an error. Do you reveice a specific warning message?

Comment: You can create some stub classes to replace the external dependency. Then you can compile your class without error. But you cannot run your code correctly with there stub classes.

Comment: @lealceldeiro I usually agree but seeing unresolved references is easier with an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was wrong. Needed references was in libs folder, and Android Studio was not able to see these references.

It was an Android Studio bug, updating it fixed my issue.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you don't reference any specific class.
The character `*` in this case stands for a wildcard import, which imports every class in the package `com.panframe.android.lib`.

Without knowing anything about your package structure, I guess you have some classes in the package `com.panframe.android.lib`. Otherwise you would get an error.

Comment: I don't have any classes with package ```com.panframe.android.lib```

Comment: Is this code under your control? Can you simply remove the import statement? Do you have any subpackages under `com.panframe.android.lib`? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16976064/java-cant-import-com-package-wildcard

Comment: When I remove the import statement it does not compile anymore. When I replace wildcard with FQCNs it does not compile either.

Comment: What errors do you get, if you remove the import statement?

Comment: I do not have anything that relates to ```com.panframe.android.lib```

Comment: basicly "error: cannot find symbol" for every class referenced which is red in the image

Comment: Is this your first (and only?) library you added to your project(s)? Maybe you didn't add it the the classpath correctly. You could also try to auto organize the imports, if you dont add them automatically yet. ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22272524/how-to-auto-import-the-necessary-classes-in-android-studio-with-shortcut/29967269 )

Comment: I'm using gradle to organize dependencies. This class (and the project) compiles. The import does not relate to any external dependencies but I have nearly 100 external dependencies. This project is currently working, on the production project. Somehow required dependency is removed and I'm left with an unsatisfiable dependency. Even tho I can still compile this.