# Why Can I Import a Specific Class But Not Its Package in Java?

Tags: java, class, import, package

I am new to Java, so having a difficult time understanding the 'package' paradigm.

I am using someone else's package, Framework, to build my program off of.

When I do this, everything works fine:

```
import Framework.Item1;
import Framework.Item2;
import Framework.Item3;
```

When I do this, nothing works:

```
import Framework.*;
```

It fails when I try to compile using javac.exe at console, it stops at compile time.  The error reads:

```
error: cannot access Item1
bad class file: ...\Framework\Item1.class
class file contains wrong clsas: Framework.Item1
Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath
```

But I have checked, double checked, triple checked, and quadruple checked that the files are in the correct places; and besides, wouldn't it fail when importing by specific class name if that were the problem, anyway?  I have been stumped for a while before I decided I need to ask for help on this one.  :(

**Edit**: After trying many solutions both simple and complex, the answer was finally to just save all my work, clean the project and recompile.  Then everything worked like magic.

If anyone could explain what would cause a situation like this so that I could prevent it in the future, I would be much obliged.

Comment: Should be useful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/631682/help-with-packages-in-java-import-does-not-work

Comment: Try `javac -cp . *.java`

Comment: Sometimes mysterious things happen, usually doing a cleaning of the project can work miracles

Comment: Thank you @ghoulfolk - after trying all manner of difficult solutions, it came down to something as simple as this.  I still don't know why, but just deleting a lot of files and recompiling from scratch finally made it work.  Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you have a naming clash between a package and a class. There may have been some refactoring which left old class files around.

The error you have would occur if `Framework` was not a package, but a class, which contained `Item1` as its nested class. Another possibility is that you are just using the wrong directory as the source code root when compiling.

In any case, if the Java naming conventions were followed, the package would not be called `Framework` but `framework` and this situation would not arise.